# Vue3 - vuetify - v-dialog form that does not close after submit button is pressed

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I created a v-dialog form using Vuetify with some text-fields that are checked by some rules

For instance:

```
<v-dialog
persistent
max-width="1024"
>
     <v-text-field
        v-model="lastname"
        :rules="nameRules"
        :counter="10"
        label="Last name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
```

I implemented a button to submit the information in the form which works well. However, the rules are only checked (and errors displayed), if the button is of type submit, like this:

```
    <v-btn type="submit" @click="addNewMember()" class="mt-2" size="large">Add new member</v-btn>
```

However, now the v-dialog disappears when the type="submit" is used. This is normal behavior but I would like users to add new information right away, for instance by resetting the input fields and showing a snackbar that the previous data was entered properly.

If I remove the type="submit", adding a new member still works but now the rules are not evaluated for the input fields and errors are not shown.

Is there a way to prevent the closing of the v-dialog? If I remove the type="submit", adding a new member still works but now the rules are not evaluated for the input fields and errors are not shown.

Comment: how do you display the v-dialog?  shouldn't it be controlled with a v-model?  when v-model is true the dialog is displayed, and when false is hidden.  If using v-model you should have direct control over when and how the v-dialog displays and closes itself.

Comment: Agree with @yoduh's comment. Additionally, to show the error in the form's input fields use the `$refs.form.validate()` method of the form which will check if all required input fields are validated or not.